# ModeShape 5.1 & CMIS 1.1

Tags: cmis, modeshape

Has someone managed to configure modeshape 5.1 to be compliance with CMIS 1.1?

According to documentation modeshape supports CMIS 1.1 repository but when you try to get repository info, you will get the answer 1.0.

I asked in Modeshape forum, but they did not give me an answer if they had tested whether modeshape 5.1 is working with CMIS 1.1 or not.

As they told me, they just implement CMIS 1.1 but do not test whether it works or not, disappointing.

Is there any other open source product that implements CMIS and JCR 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ModeShape, I am not that familiar with the product, but according to [this page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE40/ModeShape's+CMIS+Service?_sscc=t), there are multiple end points for both CMIS 1.0 and CMIS 1.1. Maybe you are using the 1.0 end point when you instead should be using the 1.1 end point.

As to your other question, Alfresco and Nuxeo both are open source and implement CMIS 1.1. I do not know the status of either product's JCR compliance because, at least with Alfresco, no one uses JCR any more. Plus, if you are using CMIS you should not need JCR.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your answer. I know that but what ever endpoint you take it always return repository that supports CMIS 1.0 I'm looking actually for some solution that support CMIS 1.1 Do you know for some?

Comment: As I mentioned, Alfresco and Nuxeo are both open source repositories that support CMIS 1.1.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, it help us to find our way in the jungle of CMIS :-).

Comment: Could you help us how to create new CMIS Type using CMIS Workbench. I have tried to export existing Type to XML, changed the exported XML file to something like that: <cmis:id>FirstFile</cmis:id>
    <cmis:localName>FirstFile</cmis:localName>
    ... then tried to import that file, but always comes exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Servers can support CMIS 1.1 without supporting a feature of the spec called type mutability. For example, Alfresco does not support type mutability, so you might be able to export type definitions from Workbench using Alfresco but you will not be able to import.For further help on this please start a new topic.